# Need more explanation for finalize(), sample exam

Tags: java, scjp

Given:

```
class Finalizer {
    static int x = 0;
    static boolean gc = false;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(x=0; x<100000; x++) {
            new Finalizer().finalize();
        }
        x = 0;
        gc = true;
        System.gc();
    }
    protected void finalize() {
        if(gc == true) x++;
        if(x % 10000 == 0)
           System.out.println(gc + " " + x);
    }
}
```

Which are always true? (Choose all that apply.)

```
A: true will never be an output
B: true will be output at least ones
C: If true and false are both output, their respective values for x can be the same.
D: If true and false are both output, their respective values for x can never be the same.
```

The solution says C is correct, and I do not understand why, can someone please explain what is happening here.

Comment: Have you tried simply running the code? What were your findings?

Comment: Since you won't be able to run this code on a real exam, I'd recommend tracing through it by hand (just enough to see what it's doing, not all 100,000 iterations of that loop). This will help you see what the code is doing, and then you can see why C is correct.

Comment: Note that if he sees why C is true, he still has to understand why A and B are incorrect.  (The exam says to choose _all_ the statements that are always true.  C and D can't both be correct, since they're mutually exclusive.)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I've tried it, and running the code does not provide enough information to explain much of anything.  At least on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going on is this: `finalize()` overrides a method in the `Object` class.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29) explains when this is called.  When an object is no longer referenced anywhere, it may then be garbage-collected; but *when* it's garbage-collected isn't defined by the language.

The `finalize()` method will be called on each `Finalize` object when it's garbage-collected.  Of course, the code you posted also calls `finalize()` explicitly.

In this example, the loop will call `new Finalize()` 100,000 times to create new `Finalize` objects.  Each time a new object is created, it's used to call `finalize()` explicitly, but then it's no longer used, so it could be garbage-collected right away.  The consequence of this is that by the time we get to the `System.gc()` call, we don't know how many `Finalize` objects are still around waiting to be garbage-collected, but it could be anywhere from 0 to 100,000.  (On my machine, it seems to be 1.  That is, it's already garbage-collected all but one of the objects, and called `finalize()` on them.)

During the first loop, `x` will go from 0 to 999,999 (the `finalize()` method won't modify `x`), and therefore you should see `false x` for every `x` that is a multiple of 10,000.  (Note that `finalize()` could also be called by the runtime for objects that are garbage-collected early, so in theory it's possible to see `false x` for the same `x` more than once.)

After the first loop, if *N* is the number of objects still to be garbage-collected, then `System.gc()` should cause them all to be garbage-collected at that point (it's not guaranteed); since `x` has been reset to 0 and `finalize()` *will* increment it, that means `x` will go from 1 to *N*.  (Note that the first `finalize()` will increment `x` from 0 to 1 before the `x % 10000` test.)  You should see `true x` for every `x` in the range 1 to *N* that is a multiple of 10,000.

But since *N* could be anything from 0 to 100,000, that means that we may or may not see any `true` outputs--we can't tell.  That's why neither A nor B is "always true".  If we do see any `true` outputs, since the output will show every multiple of 10,000 in its range, it's certain that the `true` output will have the same number as a previous `false` output, which explains why C is correct and D is not.